# Crashing Livewallpaper

Tags: android, random, canvas, live-wallpaper

I'm working on a live wallpaper and I want to have some images randomly placed
on the background of a surfaceview, everything works in the emulator but when i
run it on my the program crashes. I dont know how to get an actual log on my phone
because its not rooted.

### Below is the code:

```
Bitmap TOAD = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mushroom);
Canvas cb = new Canvas(Achtergrond); 
for (int m = 0;m < 50;m++)
{
cb.drawBitmap(TOAD, r.nextInt(SchermX), r.nextInt(SchermY), mPaint);
}
```

---

On the emulator the toadstools are added and runs correctly, but on my galaxy it crashed

Is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention that SchermX = random screenwidth
and SchermY is random screen height

Comment: Root is not required for log access. Enable USB Debugging in Settings and then run `adb logcat` with your device connected to your computer and any drivers configured.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now know that the error is, time to find to look for
a solution.
The error is:
E/AndroidRuntime(24031): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Immutable bitmap passed to Canvas constructor

Comment: I'm guessing that `Achtergrond` is your background bitmap that you loaded from a resource? Try drawing both this background and your smaller images into your surface instead of drawing the smaller images into the background bitmap.

Comment: Hey Adamp, I manage to fix it to copy the bitmap that is loaded from a resource to a new bitmap, after that I can draw on the bitmap and draw it as background.
I needed to use this mechanism because I need to create a bitmap background with a few images on it that contain transparency. The bitmap is only generated on start or wakeup. I found out that the app will have a lot slowdown when images with transparency are drawn on the surfaceview directly, so now all it working ok.